# Connection timeout after file upload + redirect Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

For an order system I made using Laravel users are able to upload files related to an order. These are send via an ajax call and processed by a Laravel controller, after which the page is reloaded.

Now the problem which I'm having is that at a certain point, after an user has uploaded some files in a short period of time and they want to upload another file, they are greeded with an ERR_CONNECTION_TIME_OUT. Note that the file is uploaded succesfully each time.

I checked the Apache and Laravel error logs and there is nothing relevant there. I also checked the php.ini upload limits and execution times and I don't think they cause any issue as they are set to 128Mb (they only upload PDFs), and 30sec respectively.

Am I missing something here?

Ajax:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
         'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
   }
});

$("#upload").on( "click", function() {
        var files = $('input[name=global_file]')[0].files;
        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append('global_file',files[0]);
        fd.append('tm_num', {{ $order['tm_num'] }});

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/admin/order/upload',
            data: fd,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function () {
                window.location.reload();
            }
        });
    });
```

Controller.php:

```
public function UploadOrderFile(Request $request)
    {
        $data = $request->all();
        $file = $request->file('global_file');

        $basepath = base_path();
        $destinationPath = $basepath.'/orders/'.$data['tm_num'];
        $fileName = $file->getClientOriginalName(); 

        $file->move($destinationPath,$fileName);
        
        return;
    }
```

Comment: *Unrelated* why there is no validation of file being uploaded; also users can upload any extension (for e.g. php backdoor), which is risk to your security of application.

Comment: @OMiShah Yes I'm aware of that, it's still in the testing phase so I will implement that later but thanks for the heads-up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few days of trail & error and wandering through server logs, I have found the problem and solution. It appeared that after a few uploads the firewall (modsecurity) stepped in and soft banned the IP for a couple of minutes after receiving the errors below on each upload (found in modsec_audit.log). After like 4-5 sets of these errors connection for the IP was blocked.

```
ModSecurity: Warning. Match of "rx ^$" against "FILES:global_file" required. [file "/etc/httpd/conf/modsecurity.d/rules/custom/000_i360_0.conf"] [line "112"] [id "77317957"] etc.....

ModSecurity: Warning. Match of "rx ^$" against "FILES_TMPNAMES:global_file" required. [file "/etc/httpd/conf/modsecurity.d/rules/custom/000_i360_0.conf"] [line "112"] [id "77317957"] etc.....
```

To solve the problem I excluded rule 77317957 (which is the ID found in the error) for this site, as I do not want any restrictions for file uploads.

Note that in my case file uploading is only available for registered users (which I manually register) so nobody has access to this besides people I know. So for others who experience the same problem I recommend to not exclude but to change/loosen the specific rule for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});

public function UploadOrderFile(Request $request)
    {
        $data = $request->all();
  if(!$request->hasFile('global_file')) return false;

        $file = $request->file('global_file');

        $basepath = base_path();
        $destinationPath = $basepath.'/orders/'.$data['tm_num'];
        $fileName = $file->getClientOriginalName(); 

        $request->store($destinationPath."/".$fileName);
        
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Same as for the answer above, CRSF token is already set globally. Why would `$request->store` make a difference here?

Answer (score 0):

On ajax headers, need to set the csrf token to access the request.

```
$("#upload").on( "click", function() {
        var files = $('input[name=global_file]')[0].files;
        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append('global_file',files[0]);
        fd.append('tm_num', {{ $order['tm_num'] }});

        $.ajax({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            },
            type: "POST",
            url: '/admin/order/upload',
            data: fd,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function () {
                window.location.reload();
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: CRSF token is set globally, which is why I did not included it in the code above. I edited it in for clarity. If the lack of a token was the problem the upload would fail instantly which it didnt as the upload itself is succesful everytime